# OroCommerce - Symfony: How to override Entity(Custom Customer Register Account)

Tags: php, symfony, entity, orocommerce

I’m trying to make a **custom customer register form**

And to do so, i’ve to override this 2 file:

CustomerBundle\Layout\DataProvider\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationFormProvider.php
and
CustomerBundle\Form\Type\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType.php

So i’ve put this code in **config/config.yml** and it work as expected:

```
services:
    oro_customer.provider.frontend_customer_user_registration_form:
        class: 'My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Layout\DataProvider\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationFormProvider'
        arguments:
            - "@form.factory"
            - "@doctrine"
            - "@oro_config.manager"
            - "@oro_website.manager"
            - "@oro_user.manager"
            - '@router'
        tags:
            - { name: layout.data_provider, alias: oro_customer_frontend_customer_user_register }

    oro_customer.form.type.frontend.customer_user.register:
        class: 'My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType'
        arguments:
            - '@oro_config.manager'
            - '@oro_user.manager'
        calls:
            - [setDataClass, ['%oro_customer.entity.customer_user.class%']]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: oro_customer_frontend_customer_user_register }
```

But i also need to override entity as well, so it will render a new column to the customer register form.

I’ve notice that **FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType** have this code:

```
calls:
            - [setDataClass, ['%oro_customer.entity.customer_user.class%']]
```

And so **CustomerBundle\Resources\config\services.yml** have that too:

```
parameters:
           oro_customer.entity.customer_user.class: Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser
```

So i’ve override it using **config/config.yml**:

```
parameters:
    oro_customer.entity.customer_user.class: My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser
```

But it doesn’t work, it throw an error:

> The form’s view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser, but is an instance
>   of class Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser. You can avoid
>   this error by setting the “data_class” option to null or by adding a
>   view transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser to an instance of
>   My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser.

I think it make the override of **FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType** go wrong and failed.

Here is my overrided **FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType.php**:

```
<?php

namespace My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type;

use Oro\Bundle\ConfigBundle\Config\ConfigManager;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType as OroFrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType;

class FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType extends OroFrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType
{

    /**
     * @var ConfigManager
     */
    protected $configManager;

    /**
     * @param ConfigManager $configManager
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     */
    public function __construct(ConfigManager $configManager, UserManager $userManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($configManager, $userManager);
        $this->configManager = $configManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($this->isCompanyNameFieldEnabled()) {
            $builder->add(
                'companyName',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.profile.company_name',
                    'constraints' => [
                        new Assert\NotBlank(),
                        new Assert\Length(['max' => 255])
                    ],
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.company_name']
                ]
            );
        }

        $builder
            ->add(
                'firstName',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.first_name.label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.first_name']
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'lastName',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.last_name.label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.last_name']
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'email',
                EmailType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.email.label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.email']
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'test',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Test Label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Test Place Holder']
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'test2',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Test2 Label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Test2 Place Holder']
                ]
            )
            ;

        $builder->add(
            'plainPassword',
            RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.password.label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.password']
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.password_confirmation.label',
                    'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'oro.customer.customeruser.placeholder.password_confirmation']
                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'oro.customer.message.password_mismatch',
                'required' => true,
                'validation_groups' => ['create']
            ]
        );

        $this->addBuilderListeners($builder);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isCompanyNameFieldEnabled()
    {
        return (bool) $this->configManager->get('oro_customer.company_name_field_enabled');
    }
}
```

Oh, and i’ve also created success 2 column “test” and “test2” in table “oro_customer_user” using **oro:migrations**.

Just ask when you need more file to check, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to override the `configureOptions` method with your `data_class`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{

    parent::configureOptions($resolver);
    $resolver->setDefault('data_class',  \My_Code\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser::class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i've try this solution and worked
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JLRrnoMOAbGMvTX33_Xh8vN-xxyb2kNV

Comment: hello, may you help me with this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373313/symfony-orocommerce-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-t0