# Symfony - Orocommerce: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t0"

Tags: php, symfony, orocommerce

I'm trying to custom the "**updateAction**" customer of symfony - orocommerce, and after trying a lot, it throw this error message in log file:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException:
>   "An exception occurred while executing:
>   
>   
>   'SELECT t1.serialized_data AS
>   serialized_data_2, t1.id AS id_3, t1.confirmed AS confirmed_4,
>   t1.email AS email_5, t1.email_lowercase AS email_lowercase_6,
>   t1.name_prefix AS name_prefix_7, t1.first_name AS first_name_8,
>   t1.middle_name AS middle_name_9, t1.last_name AS last_name_10,
>   t1.name_suffix AS name_suffix_11, t1.birthday AS birthday_12,
>   t1.created_at AS created_at_13, t1.updated_at AS updated_at_14,
>   t1.enabled AS enabled_15, t1.login_count AS login_count_16,
>   t1.username AS username_17, t1.is_guest AS is_guest_18, t1.password AS
>   password_19, t1.salt AS salt_20, t1.last_login AS last_login_21,
>   t1.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_22, t1.password_requested
>   AS password_requested_23, t1.password_changed AS password_changed_24,
>   t1.pharmacy_name AS pharmacy_name_25, t1.pharmacy_address AS
>   pharmacy_address_26, t1.pbs_approval_number AS pbs_approval_number_27,
>   t1.business_name AS business_name_28, t1.australian_business_number AS
>   australian_business_number_29, t1.business_phone_number AS
>   business_phone_number_30, t1.fax_number AS fax_number_31,
>   t1.pharmacy_owner_full_name AS pharmacy_owner_full_name_32,
>   t1.ahpra_no AS ahpra_no_33, t1.group_name AS group_name_34,
>   t1.group_contact_name AS group_contact_name_35, t1.group_contact_email
>   AS group_contact_email_36, t1.group_contact_phone_number AS
>   group_contact_phone_number_37, t1.customer_id AS customer_id_38,
>   t1.owner_id AS owner_id_39, t1.website_id AS website_id_40,
>   t1.organization_id AS organization_id_41 FROM oro_customer_user t1
>   WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["94"]:
>   
>   SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined
>   table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t0" LINE 1:
>   ...rganization_id_41 FROM oro_customer_user t1 WHERE t0.id = '9

Which can be short write like this:

```
SELECT * FROM oro_customer_user t1 WHERE t0.id = 94
```

After searching about this, seem like i've not extends the entity the right way, so may i know how to do this?

Here is my code:

> MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Controller\CustomerUserController

```
<?php

namespace MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Controller;

use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser;
use MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser as MyCodeCustomerUser;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Handler\CustomerUserHandler;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerUserType;
use MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerUserType as MyCodeCustomerUserType;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityBundle\ORM\DoctrineHelper;
use Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Annotation\Acl;
use Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Annotation\AclAncestor;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Controller\CustomerUserController as OroCustomerUserController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerUserController extends Controller
{
/**
     * Edit customer user form
     *
     * @Route("/update/{id}", name="oro_customer_customer_user_update", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     * @Template
     * @Acl(
     *      id="oro_customer_customer_user_update",
     *      type="entity",
     *      class="MyCodeCustomerBundle:CustomerUser",
     *      permission="EDIT"
     * )
     * @param MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser
     * @param Request     $request
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function updateAction(MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser, Request $request)
    {
        die('1');
        return $this->MyCodeUpdate($customerUser, $request);
    }

    /**
     * @param MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser
     * @param Request     $request
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function MyCodeUpdate(MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser, Request $request)
    {        
        $form = $this->createForm(MyCodeCustomerUserType::class, $customerUser);
        $handler = new CustomerUserHandler(
            $form,
            $request,
            $this->get('oro_customer_user.manager'),
            $this->get('oro_security.token_accessor'),
            $this->get('translator'),
            $this->get('logger')
        );

        $result = $this->get('oro_form.model.update_handler')->handleUpdate(
            $customerUser,
            $form,
            function (MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser) {
                return [
                    'route'      => 'mycode_customer_customer_user_update',
                    'parameters' => ['id' => $customerUser->getId()]
                ];
            },
            function (MyCodeCustomerUser $customerUser) {
                return [
                    'route'      => 'oro_customer_customer_user_view',
                    'parameters' => ['id' => $customerUser->getId()]
                ];
            },
            $this->get('translator')->trans('oro.customer.controller.customeruser.saved.message'),
            $handler
        );

        return $result;
    }
```

> MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser

```
<?php

namespace MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Model\ExtendCustomerUser;
use Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Model\EmailHolderInterface;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\Config;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\ConfigField;
use Oro\Bundle\LocaleBundle\Model\FullNameInterface;
use Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\AbstractUser;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Security\AdvancedApiUserInterface;
use Oro\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Website;
use Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUser as OroCustomerUser;

/**
 * The entity that represents a person who acts on behalf of the company
 * to buy products using OroCommerce store frontend.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="oro_customer_user")
 */
class CustomerUser extends OroCustomerUser
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="pharmacy_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $pharmacy_name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="pharmacy_address", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $pharmacy_address;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="pbs_approval_number", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $pbs_approval_number;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="business_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $business_name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="australian_business_number", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $australian_business_number;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="business_phone_number", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $business_phone_number;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="fax_number", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $fax_number;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="pharmacy_owner_full_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $pharmacy_owner_full_name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="ahpra_no", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $ahpra_no;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="group_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $group_name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="group_contact_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $group_contact_name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="group_contact_email", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $group_contact_email;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="group_contact_phone_number", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $group_contact_phone_number;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answered at the forum.
https://forum.oroinc.com/orocommerce/topic/missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-t0
Please don't post the same questions at different channels. This usually not speed up the answer, but make more work for us. 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks, i just thought that if i post on this, there will be someone who have experience about this which can lead me or give advice on this. Sorry